# extracting list of values from dictionary

Tags: python

From a python dictionary we have multiple lists. Need to get all the lists from the dictionary my code is getting only the last list.

1) Have created a dictionary
2) created a list variable
3) looping over the dictionary added the value in the dictionary to the list
4) now I am having list of lists.
5) Need to convert each list into a dictionary.

```
bcci_data={1:["SRT", 42], 2:["ZAK", 35], 3:["S.Ganguly", 37],4:["VVS", 38], 5:["RDravid", 37], 6:["Vsewag", 35], 7:["Akumble", 39]}
bcci_val=[]
for val in bcci_data.values():
    bcci_val.append(val)
    print(bcci_val)
print("*****")
print(bcci_val)


actual result is list of lists as below
[['SRT', 42], ['ZAK', 35], ['S.Ganguly', 37], ['VVS', 38], ['RDravid', 37], ['Vsewag', 35], ['Akumble', 39]]

need to convert each list into a dictionary.
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dict` and list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
bcci_data={1:["SRT", 42], 2:["ZAK", 35], 3:["S.Ganguly", 37],4:["VVS", 38], 5:["RDravid", 37], 6:["Vsewag", 35], 7:["Akumble", 39]}
bcci_val = [dict([val]) for val in bcci_data.values()]
print(bcci_val)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'SRT': 42},
 {'ZAK': 35},
 {'S.Ganguly': 37},
 {'VVS': 38},
 {'RDravid': 37},
 {'Vsewag': 35},
 {'Akumble': 39}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> bcci_data={1:["SRT", 42], 2:["ZAK", 35], 3:["S.Ganguly", 37],4:["VVS", 38], 5:["RDravid", 37], 6:["Vsewag", 35], 7:["Akumble", 39]}
>>> bcci_val=[]
>>> for val in bcci_data.values():
...     bcci_val.append(val)
...     print(bcci_val)
...
[['SRT', 42]]
[['SRT', 42], ['ZAK', 35]]
[['SRT', 42], ['ZAK', 35], ['S.Ganguly', 37]]
[['SRT', 42], ['ZAK', 35], ['S.Ganguly', 37], ['VVS', 38]]
[['SRT', 42], ['ZAK', 35], ['S.Ganguly', 37], ['VVS', 38], ['RDravid', 37]]
[['SRT', 42], ['ZAK', 35], ['S.Ganguly', 37], ['VVS', 38], ['RDravid', 37], ['Vsewag', 35]]
[['SRT', 42], ['ZAK', 35], ['S.Ganguly', 37], ['VVS', 38], ['RDravid', 37], ['Vsewag', 35], ['Akumble', 39]]
>>> print("*****")
*****
>>> print(bcci_val)
[['SRT', 42], ['ZAK', 35], ['S.Ganguly', 37], ['VVS', 38], ['RDravid', 37], ['Vsewag', 35], ['Akumble', 39]]
>>>
>>>
>>> d = {}
>>> for element in bcci_val:
...     d[element[0]] = element[1]
...
>>> d  #dictionary with the required values
{'SRT': 42, 'ZAK': 35, 'S.Ganguly': 37, 'VVS': 38, 'RDravid': 37, 'Vsewag': 35, 'Akumble': 39}
>>>
```

This might help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
bcci_data={1:["SRT", 42], 2:["ZAK", 35], 3:["S.Ganguly", 37],4:["VVS", 38], 5:["RDravid", 37], 6:["Vsewag", 35], 7:["Akumble", 39]}
dict(bcci_data.values())
```

output :

```
{'SRT': 42,
 'ZAK': 35,
 'S.Ganguly': 37,
 'VVS': 38,
 'RDravid': 37,
 'Vsewag': 35,
 'Akumble': 39}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can list comprehension such as below.

```
bcci_val = [dict([value]) for value in bcci_data.values()]
```

You will get your required dict as bcci_val.